# Elementary differential equations: Please give a proof of the trick

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

Here is a statement (or theorem) from my book:

> **$\pmb{\text{A neat trick: Turning nonlinear separable equations into linear separable equations}}$**
>
> $\mathcal{\text{Knowing when to substitute:}}$
>
> You can use the trick of setting $y=xv$ when you have differential equation that is of the form:
>
> $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$
>
> when $f(x,y)=f(tx,ty)$ where $t$ is a constant.

I understand this. But the book gives no proof. I mean how can we ensure that the trick of setting $y=xv$ will always work whenever $f(x,y)=f(tx,ty)$

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just plug $y=xv$ in the equation.

$$\frac{d(xv)}{dx}=x\frac{dv}{dx}+v=f(x,xv)$$

and

$$\frac{dv}{f(1,v)-v}=\frac{dx}x.$$

---

Alternatively,

$$f(tx,ty)=f(x,y)\iff f(x,y)=g\left(\frac yx\right)=g(v)$$ and the equation is

$$xv'+v=g(v).$$

Comment: If $f(x,y)=f(tx,ty)$, how can we always express $f(x,y)$ as a function of $\dfrac{y}{x}$?

Comment: @Oliver: hem, $t=1/x$.

Comment: Yves: THANKS FOR HELPING... However I am a bit confused here. (1) Why is $t=1/x$? (2) It is said in the question that $t$ is a constant.

Comment: @Oliver: you are right. $t$ constant is a misleading statement. Because $f(x,y)=f(tx,ty)\to f(t^nx,t^ny)$ by induction and you can generalize to rational exponents. So $t$ is a weird constant...